# Trying to send a POST request and get json data but getting 400

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm trying to send an ajax POST request and I've set the content type to be `application/json` etc. But in the backend I keep getting `400 (BAD REQUEST)`. What's wrong with the code?

```
var data = {key0: 'val0', key1: 'val1'};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/users',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  },
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Flask:

```
@usersapi.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    #raise Exception(request.headers.get('Content-Type'))
    d = dict(request.get_json())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending JSON.

You've passed `data` an object, so it is being serialised as form data.

You need to explicitly convert it to JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```